# Use external extensions in Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla, content-management-system

Is it possible to use an extension in 1 website for another. The plug-in that i want to use isnt available in de extension market but we want to use it because or employees dont understand other plugins. The plugin that we use is the MarketPlace plugin from CodingFish.

An example.

Site 1:
Has marketplace 2.3.5

Site 2±
Doesnt have marketplace.

How can we get the extension from site 1 in site 2=

I hope the SO people can help me with this problem because i did not find an solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about using `iframes`?

Comment: how can i do that the easiest way?

Comment: You can create a custom jomla template on `site 1`, a blank template, without modules etc and access it by adding `?template=your_blank_template_name` in the iframe.

Comment: Assming site 2 is also powered by Joomla, can you not simply install this extension on it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be quickest to check out the developer's website: https://www.codingfish.com or browse through their forums at https://www.codingfish.com/forums.  Contact information from them can be found in the footer of the website.